# Ajuda com manipualação de Div

Tags: html, css, css3

Boa tarde. Preciso de ajuda com a manipulação de uma Div. Em teoria, apenas tenho que passar uma div 'curvada ' por cima de outra, porém, não apenas um circulo e sim algo mais suavizado, como no print abaixo:

- https://ibb.co/nzGLPk

Como vocês fariam isso? ps: Não tenho código pronto ainda, gostaria apenas de entender a lógica do CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Existe um estilo chamado `border-radius`, como ele você pode controlar a tal "curva" mencionada por você.

você pode manipular o *top,right,left* e *bottom* do objeto.

**Exemplo**

```css
div{
width: 120px;
height: 90px;
border: 1px solid;
border-top-left-radius: 80%;
border-top-right-radius: 80%;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

[Aqui](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-radius.asp) você encontra tudo relacionado ao `border-radius`